# Шуфлядка — это русское или белорусское слово?

Tags: этимология, выбор-слов, значение-слов

Недавно приехал в Беларусь и услышал слово **шуфлядка**, которое, по утверждению местных, считается белорусским словом. Так ли это на самом деле?
Ну и попутно, может кто-нибудь рассказать — откуда это слово появилось?

Comment: Странно, Вы так много хотели узнать, а довольствовались такой малостью.

Comment: Я так понимаю, что немецкое слово через польский язык пришло в русский язык в Прибалтике /в белорусский/в украинский. Поэтому распостранение этого слова и было ограничено западными краями российской империи. Там эти народы соприкасались с поляками.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чисто белорусское слово. Есть однокоренные слова аналогичного смысла: шуфель — совковая лопата; шуфлявать — этой лопатой производить возвратно-поступательные движения (вперёд-назад). Шуфляда (шуфлядка), маленький выдвижной ящик стола, производит точно такие же действия, как и шуфлявать.
Да и длинно это, говорить "выдвижной ящик стола", проще сказать "шуфляда".
Белорусский язык очень мелодичный и красивый — по красоте на втором месте после итальянского, из-за аканья.
Более подробно: "Комсомолка в Беларуси" (https://www.kp.by/daily/26645.5/3664846/).
Вообще в России много заимствованных наших слов, да и генетических белорусов тоже.

Comment: Белорусское - да.
Чисто белорусское - точно нет.
Немецкий - Schublade, украинский - Шухляда, польский - Szuflada, голландский - Lade + schuif (2 слова).

Answer (score 10):

[**шуфлядка**](https://argo.academic.ru/6356/%D1%88%D1%83%D1%84%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0)

1. Выдвижной ящик (стола, комода, шкафа и т.п.).
   Происходит от немецкого слова *Schublade* (с тем же значением) через польские *szuflada* и *szufladka*.
   Это слово широко распространено в Латвии, в Белоруссии (где является по сути литературным), на Украине (с Х), встречается в Средней Азии, в Молдавии, возможно – в остальной Прибалтике, и иногда – в России.
2. Любая выдвижная полка.
3. Выдвижной модуль в электрических распределительных шкафах.

Есть такие [**версии возникновения**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ruwiki/1204977/%D0%A8%D1%83%D1%84%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0) этого слова:

1. Слово **шуфлядка** (укр. *шухлядка* или *шухляда*) пришло от нем. *Schublade* (нем. *Schub* — толкать) и заимствовано славянскими народами у австрийцев.
2. Образовано от польск. *Szuflada* или *Szufladka* — возможно, с появлением в конце сороковых годов переселенцев и ссыльных из Польши.

В универсальном дополнительном практическом толковом словаре [И. Мостицкого](https://mostitsky_universal.academic.ru/6261/%D1%88%D1%83%D1%84%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%BA%D0%B0) утверждается, что это белорусское слово. Присутствует слово и во многих украинских словарях (с вариациями).
А ведь нашлось и в русском [словаре синонимов В. Н. Тришина (2013)](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/204915/%D1%8F%D1%89%D0%B8%D0%BA):
ящик (сущ., кол-во синонимов: 61) — шуфлядка, шухлядка.

*Анна Владимировна присела на угловой диван на кухне и достала из шуфлядки кухонного комода потрепанный кошелек.*
А. Чиж-Литаж. Дары Бога

*Она хитро улыбнулась и достала из шуфлядки чернильную ручку.*
Анте Наудис. Придорожное солнце

P. S. Мне это слово раньше не встречалось (Эстония, Санкт-Петербург, Новгород), поэтому выводы делать не берусь.

Answer (score 2):

Тут есть две части вопроса: происхождение и современное использование.
Про происхождение написали уже.

Использование:

В Беларуси это слово используют повсеместно в обоих языках. То есть это такое же привычное слово, как "стол", "стул" и т. д. Белорусы искренне удивляются, когда носители русского языка из других стран это слово не понимают.

Answer (score 0):

Боже мой, на пятом десятке лет и имея мужа-мебельщика, впервые услышала это слово от девушки, выросшей в Белоруссии. Думала, что это какое-то простонародное словцо.

Comment: В опубликованном сообщении не содержится решения вопроса. Когда ваша [репутация](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) достигнет необходимого уровня, вы сможете [оставлять комментарии к любому сообщению](https://rus.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); на данный момент, пожалуйста, [внесите улучшающую правку в ваше сообщение, чтобы оно отвечало на вопрос без дополнительных уточнений от автора](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). — [из очереди проверок](/review/late-answers/43602)